# How can I sum all Disk Size (of each partition) using PHPseclib

Tags: php, linux

I'm using phpseclib library. I'm trying to get total disk space of each partition where output is similar to

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              242968      0    242968   0% /dev
tmpfs              50012   1804     48208   4% /run
/dev/vda1       20263528 845116  19402028   5% /
tmpfs             250048      0    250048   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120      0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             250048      0    250048   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50012      0     50012   0% /run/user/0
```

I've tried to use expload() command which adds extra hassle of summing it up
How can get total sum of 1K-block column from command line.

Update: `df --total | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`

Comment: to sum the **Available** + **Used** spaces? Besides, show the expected output

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: If you had to tackle this by yourself, where would you start?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest To sum all rows of Available Row.

Comment: Iterate over the fourth column `+=`.

Comment: @Chris I am totally out of ideas! Doesn't even seems possible via preg_match_all.

Comment: Not every string problem is a regex problem. Have you considered splitting this into rows, then splitting on whitespace?

Comment: @ChiragAggarwal, I would suggest a command-line solution if that suits you - let me know

Comment: Run `df --total` and take the last line.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I would really prefer that if possible.

Comment: Let me try all above solutions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or maybe `df --total | awk '{ print $4 }'` an use the last row/line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one of the most shortest solutions would look like:

```
df --total | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

---

`tail -n 1` - outputs the last line of the input

`awk '{print $4}'` - prints the **4**th field value(i.e. *total available space*)

Comment: Worked just perfectly. Got answers to both questions! Thanks to both